# Which one is preferable : Rx-Subject or Android BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, rx-java2, subject-observer

I have following project in Github : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/ExoPlayer-Service where I play music using ExoPlayer from Assets.

When I click on Play/Pause button, I send a broadcast to Play/Pause ExoPlayer :

```
public void playPauseClick(View view) {
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
        Intent intent = new Intent(STR_RECEIVER_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra(IS_PLAYING, isPlaying);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And here is my BroadcastReceiver which registered in my Android Service :

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean isPlaying = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_PLAYING, false);
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(isPlaying);
        }
    };
```

Another approach is using Rx-Subject. So in my Activity I use onNext() to Play/pause the ExoPlayer :

```
public void playPauseClick(View view) {
     isPlaying = !isPlaying;
     PLAYING_SUBJECT.onNext(isPlaying);
}
```

And in the Service I have following Disposable, which I dispose in onDestroy() :

```
public static final Subject<Boolean> PLAYING_SUBJECT = PublishSubject.create();

private final Disposable mPlayingDisposable = PLAYING_SUBJECT.subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Boolean isPlaying) {
            mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(isPlaying);
        }
    });
```

both broadcast and Rx-Subject works as expected, but in your point of view which one is preferable upon another and why in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** use IPC (inter-process communication) for communications within your own process. Not only is it wasteful of resources, but it introduces security problems. For example, *any app* can send that broadcast to you.

Whether you use RxJava or something else (Kotlin's `SharedFlow`, `LiveData`, etc.) that is in-process is up to you. But, please, do not use system broadcasts for in-process communications.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about wasteful of resources, but regarding security, we can set android:exported="false" in manifest and as a result other apps can not send that broadcast. Do you agree?

Comment: @Ali: "Do you agree?" -- then your receiver would have no access to `mExoPlayer`, unless you are doing some scary stuff (e.g., making `mExoPlayer` be `static`). I assume that this receiver is registered via `registerReceiver()` called on a `Context`, and AFAIK there is no equivalent of `android:exported="false"` in that scenario.

Comment: You are right, it is registered via registerReceiver(). Thank you for your help.